# Fast copy of Color32[] array to byte[] array

Tags: c#, struct, copy, unity-game-engine, marshalling

What would be a fast method to **copy/convert** an `array` of `Color32[]` values to a `byte[]` buffer?
`Color32` is a struct from Unity 3D containing `4 bytes, R, G, B and A respectively`.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to send the rendered image from unity through a pipe to another application (`Windows Forms`). Currently I'm using this code:

```
private static byte[] Color32ArrayToByteArray(Color32[] colors)
{
    int length = 4 * colors.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(colors, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, length);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return bytes;
}
```

Thankyou and sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow.
Marinescu Alexandru

Comment: So you've got that code... does it do what you want it to?

Comment: Would you please share your result, problems and your question clearly?!

Comment: It would seem so. But I was wondering whether a faster method exists...

Comment: Any speed gain in mind?

Comment: I'm sending every frame rendered from Unity through a pipe to another application. That's why I wanted to know whether a faster method exists. Currently I'm getting around 11 msec per frame for converting the Color32[] array to a byte[] array. Previously I used the EncodeToPNG() method which took around 85 msec per frame.

Comment: You are copying the data 3 times.  First to HGlobal, then to byte[], then to the pipe buffer.  Try copying it only 1 time by not converting at all.   Use BinaryWriter.

Comment: i seen someting here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/190340/how-can-i-send-a-render-texture-over-the-network.html

Answer (score 11):

I ended up using this code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private static byte[] Color32ArrayToByteArray(Color32[] colors)
{
    if (colors == null || colors.Length == 0)
        return null;

    int lengthOfColor32 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Color32));
    int length = lengthOfColor32 * colors.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

    GCHandle handle = default(GCHandle);
    try
    {
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(colors, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, length);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (handle != default(GCHandle))
            handle.Free();
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Which is fast enough for my needs.

Comment: i used this script to make a webcam screenshot method:
`static byte[] ScreenshotWebcam(WebCamTexture wct) { Texture2D colorTex = new Texture2D(wct.width, wct.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false); colorTex.LoadRawTextureData(Color32ArrayToByteArray(wct.GetPixels32())); colorTex.Apply(); return colorTex.EncodeToPNG(); }`

Answer (score 4):

With modern .NET, you can use spans for this:

```cs
var bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Color32, byte>(colors);
```

This gives you a `Span<byte>` that covers the same data. The API is directly comparable to using vectors (`byte[]`), but it isn't actually a vector, and **there is no copy**: you are directly accessing the original data. It is like an unsafe pointer coercion, but: entirely safe.

If you *need* it as a vector, `ToArray` and copy methods exist for that.

Answer (score -2):

Well why do you work with Color32?

byte[] Bytes = tex.GetRawTextureData();
.
.
.
Tex.LoadRawTextureData(Bytes);
Tex.Apply();