# How do I make Unity save output pngs to a relative path instead of absolute?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my game to save a png. Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493876/how-to-save-a-png-using-unity-webcamtexture) I can do that, but how/where do I save them to a path relative to the game and not specific to my computer?

Is there a path similar to how PlayerPrefs are saved such that I don't need to know or specify where they are saved, but the OS and Unity know where to create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using one of the built in path strings provided by Unity (check the sample below) and generate a path that is relative to one of those locations.

- [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)
- [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)
- [Application.streamingAssetsPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)
- [Application.temporaryCachePath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-temporaryCachePath.html)

### Usage example

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        string path = GetTemporaryImagePath();

        // Code to save an image at "path"
        // ...
    }

    private string GetTemporaryImagePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Application.temporaryCachePath, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know enough to know exactly what to ask, and this is exactly what I didn't know I needed! Thanks!