# Convert Color32 array to byte array to send over network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, image-capture, color-channel

I have been working on webcam streaming for video and photo capture on Android devices within Unity3D. Most of the examples I have found in order to capture webcam feeds use a specific WebCamTexture object in order to get access to the devices camera hardware. I currently am able to capture the camera input but the WebCamTexture stores the data as a Color32[]. I found this solution below for converting a Color32[] to a byte[] but it seems to be swapping the red and blue color channels.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21575147/8115962

Is there a way to prevent the red and blue channels from being reversed?

Comment: Sending Texture over the network is really heavy and wasting bandwidth. Why not convert it to jpg or png before sending it? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717713/unity-live-video-streaming/42727918#42727918) post....

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to Convert `Color32` array from `WebCamTexture`  to byte array:

First, create a structure to hold the converted array:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Color32Array
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] byteArray;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Color32[] colors;
}
```

The `WebCamTexture` to convert:

```
WebCamTexture webcamTex = new WebCamTexture();
```

Create new instance of that structure:

```
Color32Array colorArray = new Color32Array();
```

Initialize Color32 with the appropriate size:

```
colorArray.colors = new Color32[webcamTex.width * webcamTex.height];
```

Fill `Color32` which automatically fills byte array:

```
webcamTex.GetPixels32(colorArray.colors);
```

---

Now, you can use `colorArray.byteArray` which is byte array.

Load into Texture 2D if needed:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
tex.LoadRawTextureData(colorArray.byteArray);
tex.Apply();
```

---

Like I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575438/unity3d-webcam-streaming-for-android#comment82108073_47575438), it's better to convert the `WebCamTexture` to `Texture2D` then to **jpeg** or **png** then send it over the network. That will reduce the size of the image. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717713/unity-live-video-streaming/42727918#42727918) answer for more information.