# Fast way convert color[] to byte[]

Tags: c#, colors, byte, marshalling

[Fast copy of Color32[] array to byte[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512259/fast-copy-of-color32-array-to-byte-array)

I already saw, quiet similar question.

But I want to convert the color[] array to byte[]

```
private byte[] color2ByteArray(Color[] colors)
{
    int len = colors.Length;

    byte[] result = new byte[len * 3];

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        result[index++] = (byte)(colors[i].r * 255);

        result[index++] = (byte)(colors[i].g * 255);

        result[index++] = (byte)(colors[i].b * 255);
    }

    return result;
}
```

To obtain a proper color value and convert the byte[] array. 
I have to multiply the color x 255.

I've seen a lot of posts about Marshal.copy

But I don't know how to change it to make it faster

Comment: what `Color` are you using here? in `System.Drawing.Color`, there is no `.r` etc, and `.R` *is* a `byte`. So: what `Color` are you using? What is the **full name** of `Color` here?

Comment: @MarcGravell It is a UnityEngine.color sorry, I didn't say.  and colors[i].r is float type. 0.0~1.0  that's why I have multiplied the 255

Answer (score 2):

You're still going to have to do the math here. There *are* a few things that might help, though:

- avoid hoisting the `len` for the `for` loop, but use `colors.Length` directly - on some JITs/AOTs, this helps it elide the loop bounds checks (`for(int i = 0 ; i < someArray.Length ; i++)` is recognized as a safe array walk)
- only fetch the color out once, i.e. `var color = colors[i]` or even `ref Color color = ref colors[i]` in recent C#
- perhaps consider the `Vector` cast, allowing you to perform a vectorized multiply; i.e. `var vec = 255 * (Vector4)colors[i];`, then just cast the 3 values from `Vector4` as you fetch them

Additionally, if speed is important, I would avoid allocating an array in here; options:

- pass in a target array to be populated
- pass in a target *span* to be populated
- use a leased array, perhaps returning a custom `IDisposable` that represents the lease segment (I can go into more detail if needed)